# What are the rules for blowing conch before and after Pūjā - Upāsanā?

Tags: rituals, puja, upasana

When should the conch (शंख) be blown? At the start of the *Pūjā - Upāsanā* or at the end?

Sometimes, I have seen people blowing it twice, both at the start and then in the end too. Others, blow it once, either at start or at the end only.

Does it depend on the kind of *pūjā* being done? Like a big *pūjā* (*mahāpūjā*) has different rules and a normal *pūjā* has different rules?

What does scriptures prescribe on this?